# JSON MySQL for each date between start and end add to JSON encode

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, json

I have a table in MySQL which has a `startdate` and `enddate`.

An example of 1 row would be(disregard the naming throughout):

```
eg 
startdate -> 20121224
endate -> 20121226
title -> name
etc
```

The current script I have works great and adds to JSON for each row, BUT.....
I want to.... for each mysql row get the startdate and enddate, for each date inclusive within the startdate and enddate add to JSON encode.

**Therefor rather than the above example of 1 row returning:**

```
[{
    "user": "378",
    "date": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startdate)",
    "title": "name",
    "description": "6 Days",
    "url": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(enddate)",
    "bmanager": "manager name",
    "academic_year": "20120801",
    "division": "division name",
    "manager_id": "3"
}]
```

---

**It would return 3 JSON for the one row for each of the dates:**

```
[{
    "user": "378",
    "date": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1st date)",
    "title": "name",
    "description": "6 Days",
    "url": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1st date)",
    "bmanager": "manager name",
    "academic_year": "20120801",
    "division": "division name",
    "manager_id": "3"
}, {
    "user": "378",
    "date": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2nd date)",
    "title": "name",
    "description": "6 Days",
    "url": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2nd date)",
    "bmanager": "manager name",
    "academic_year": "20120801",
    "division": "division name",
    "manager_id": "3"
}, {
    "user": "378",
    "date": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(3rd date)",
    "title": "name",
    "description": "6 Days",
    "url": "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(3rd date)",
    "bmanager": "manager name",
    "academic_year": "20120801",
    "division": "division name",
    "manager_id": "3"
}, ]
```

---

**JSON**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/json');

    $lmanager = $_GET["lmanager"];

    $sqldata = mysql_query('
    SELECT
    requests.user,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.start_date) AS date,
    requests.employee AS title, 
    requests.days AS description,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(requests.end_date) AS url,
    business.line_manager AS bmanager,
    requests.academic_year,
    business.academic_year,
    business.division,
    line_managers.userid AS manager_id
    FROM requests 
    INNER JOIN holiday_entitlement_business_manual AS business ON requests.user=business.userid AND requests.academic_year=business.academic_year
    INNER JOIN line_managers ON business.line_manager=line_managers.name
    WHERE requests.approved = 1 AND line_managers.userid = '.$lmanager.'
    ');

    $posts = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
    {
        $row['date'] = $row['date'].'000';
        $row['url'] = $row['url'].'000';
        $row['description'] = $row['description'].' Days';
        $posts[] = $row;
    }

    mysql_free_result($sqldata);
    die(json_encode($posts));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your sql select query:

```
select datediff(requests.end_date, requests.start_date) as numdays
```

then do something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $row['numdays']; $i++){
        $row['date'] = $row['date']+$i*24*60*60; // add 24 hours in seconds to the start_date stamp
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
}
```

You may need to tweak it,